# Can't convert System.Xml.XmlNode[] to System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

I have a web service that is getting data from onther device
I have an image data type.
I select the image data from sql-db-1 on server-1 then call a web service in server-2 webservice that takes the data and saves it into sql-db-2 on server-2.

The problem is that when I'm trying to save the image on the pc or insert it into sql-db-2
I get an error: `can not convert System.Xml.XmlNode[] to System.Byte[]`

I need to know how to convert data type `System.Xml.XmlNode[]` to `System.Byte[]`.

Comment: Did you use a Service Reference or a Web Reference? Also, which version of .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what kind of data is there in the Node. But i think somthing similar like this might do:

```
    var item = xmlnode[0];
    Byte[] byteconverted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.InnerText)
```

Comment: "what kind of data is there in the Node" it's image data